# how to solve CustomStringConvertible error in swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am working in swift 2.0 with an enum to return some error messages to the user and i am using CustomStringConvertible protocol.

This is the code i have:

```
enum Error: ErrorType {
    case EmptyField
    case PasswordDoNotMatch
    case InvalidEmail
    case UserCardIDTaken
    case IncorrectSignIn
    case InvalidPassword
}

extension Error: CustomStringConvertible{
    var decription : String {
        switch self{
        case .EmptyField: return "Porfavor llene todos los campos"
        case .PasswordDoNotMatch: return "La contraseña no coincide"
        case .InvalidEmail: return "Porfavor entre un email valido"
        case .UserCardIDTaken: return "La Cedula ya existe"
        case .IncorrectSignIn: return "Email o Contraseña son incorrectos"
        case .InvalidPassword: return "Las contraseñas no coinciden"
        }
    }
}
```

And i get the follow error: "Type 'Error' does not conform to protocol CustomStringConvertible"

I want to know why that hapens.

Comment: Typo: de**s**cription

Comment: aaashh!!, thanks @vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CustomStringConvertible` protocol require a gettable variable named `description` but your declaration for it is wrong.

Assuming you want to declare a computed variable you should do

```
extension Error: CustomStringConvertible{
    var description : String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .EmptyField: return "Porfavor llene todos los campos"
            case .PasswordDoNotMatch: return "La contraseña no coincide"
            case .InvalidEmail: return "Porfavor entre un email valido"
            case .UserCardIDTaken: return "La Cedula ya existe"
            case .IncorrectSignIn: return "Email o Contraseña son incorrectos"
            case .InvalidPassword: return "Las contraseñas no coinciden"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the nested `get` in there as it's optional for computed properties.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for the tip